# How do I set value into deep properties of the Student class?

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I am still new to C#. So below is my Student class

```
class Student
{
    public partial class Document
    {
        private StudentBio studentBio;
        public StudentBio StudentBio{get;set;}
    }
    public partial class StudentBio
    {
        private StudentCourse[] studentCourse;
        public StudentCourse[] StudentCourse{get;set;}
    }

    public partial class StudentCourse
    {
        private string courseId;
        private string courseName;
        public string CourseName{get;set;}
    }
}
```

How do I set the courseId since I got error when setting the value into the field. I could not access directly like Document.StudentBio.StudentCourse.CourseId to set the value.

```
public static void Main()
{   
    Student myObject = new Student();
    Type myType = typeof(Student);
    FieldInfo myFieldInfo = myType.GetField("courseId", 
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance); 
    Console.WriteLine(myFieldInfo);
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to use reflection here?

Comment: Aside from the (unneeded) use of reflection: Why do you have property getters+setters *and* a private backing field?

Comment: You dont need Reflection to set a "deep" property.  If you have instances of those things  `Doc.Bio.Course.CourseId = 7` should work.  In the future you will want to provide a but more detail than `I got error`

Comment: @Plutonix Other then the null reference exception that will probably throw :)

Comment: Most probably I need to use reflection in order to access Doc.StudentBio.StudentCourse.CourseId  since I could not access direct as I stated.

Comment: show the error you got when you tried to do it the 'normal' way. BTW if you come from Java you will be surprised. C# nested class are quite different from Java's. In fact its really just a naming thing in C#, I wonder if thats where your confusion is coming from

Comment: Reading you code I am sure thats the issue. Creating an Instance of Student does not create a nested instance of Document, etc. You have to create them explicitly. Nesting is just a naming thing in c#

Comment: I hope you know what partial classes really are. They are not for classes inside classes (inner classes). Unless you want write a part of the class else where you don't need them.

Comment: if you simply want to ensure your courseID is only internally set, you can use `public string courseId { get; private set; }`

Comment: To be 100% clear Student has no data in ti. When you create an instance of Student you are creating an empty object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need `Reflection` to set a `deep` property. Not sure why are you making this much hierarchy , but you can solve your issue by doing following.

You must have to initialize the property in Constructor of each class to avoid `NUllReferenceExecption`

```
public class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        StudentDoc = new Document();
    }
   public Document StudentDoc { get; set; }

}
public class Document
{
    public Document()
    {
        StudentBio = new StudentBio();
    }
    public StudentBio StudentBio { get; set; }
}
public class StudentBio
{
    public StudentBio()
    {
        StudentCourse = new StudentCourse();
    }
    public StudentCourse StudentCourse { get; set; }
}
public class StudentCourse
{
    public string CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
}
```

And from Main

```
public static void Main()
{ 
        Student myObject = new Student();          
        myObject.StudentDoc.StudentBio.StudentCourse.CourseId = "10";
}
```